# How to not display duplicates from many objects in an Array

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

How can I make sure that no duplicates are displayed with vue inside a template ?
I my case the data is an array of objects and key that has a value of an object with multiple objects within it. So this would be a nested v-for in vue template syntax.

```
{
    "matches": [ 
        {
            "birthday": "1/29/2019",
            "household": {
               "0": {
                    "relationship": "brother"
                 },
               "1": {
                "relationship": "brother"
                 }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would only like to display 1 unique relationship per household. Please see fiddle for further examination https://jsfiddle.net/sxmhv3t7/

Comment: I noticed a downvote for this already. If there is a better way to ask this question please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `computed` property to make `matches` array unique.

For example:

```
  computed: {
    uniqueMatches () {
       return this.matches.map(item => {
         let households = Object.values(item.household)
         let relationships = households.map(item => item.relationship)
         const uniqueRelationships = [...new Set(relationships)]
         item.household = uniqueRelationships.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => {
            acc[idx] = {}
            acc[idx].relationship = cur
            return acc
          }, {})
          console.log(item)
         return item
       })
    }
  }
```

and then use `uniqueMatches` instead of `matches` in template

Demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/eok71utx/1/)

Comment: Thanks you this is just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You could massage the data a bit and create a `uniqueHouseholdMembers` array property on each match in the `matches` array and then just print out those values:

```
matches.forEach(match => {
  let houseHolds = Object.values(match.household);

  match.uniqueHouseholdMembers = houseHolds.reduce((acc, household) => {
    // check if household member has already been added to our growing list
    let isUniqueRelationship = !acc.includes(household.relationship);

    // add household member if unique
    if (isUniqueRelationship) {
      acc.push(household.relationship);
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
});

// output using the data you provided:
// match[0].uniqueHouseholdMembers -> ['brother']
// match[1].uniqueHouseholdMembers -> ['sister']

// and if you have a 3rd match entry with more household members:
// match[2].uniqueHouseholdMembers -> ['brother', 'father', 'stranger']
```